# Delphi Writing to HKEY LOCAL MACHINE

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a back up application that I wrote and I need it to run on start up, always for all users. I want to use

```
key := '\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run';
Reg := TRegIniFile.Create;
try
  Reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Reg.CreateKey(Key);
  if Reg.OpenKey(Key,False) then Reg.WriteString(key, 'Backup', 'c:\backup.exe');
finally
  Reg.Free;
end;
```

I have written a manifest and added it as a resource, It asks for admin privileges every time it runs. However, it is not adding the the reg value and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
```

Solved the issue. The above code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in a 32 bit process. And as such it is subject to the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). That is the technology that maintains separate 32 and 64 bit views of certain portions the registry.

The way this is implemented is that the 32 bit view of `HKLM\Software` is stored under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`. And that's where your registry writes are being re-directed to.

Now you could choose to write to the 64 bit view of the registry by using the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag. However, there's no need to do that. You can simply write to the 32 bit view of the registry. When a user logs on Windows processes the `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` startup apps from both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry.

Many programs do this. Looking at my machine I can see the following entries under `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`:

- Apple Push
- iTunesHelper
- QuickTime Task
- DivXUpdate
- SunJavaUpdate

In other words, the code in the question already works.