# Delphi, Object Pascal, Write to registry not working

Tags: delphi, registry, pascal

I am having difficulty writing a registry key. I am using a standard procedure that I have used before and calling it in the constructor. I am admin on this device. For some reason the key is not being created. I am working on a windows 10 virtual machine but I don't think that would make a difference.

```
unit FrmMainMenu;

interface

uses
 Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
 System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
 Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, tlhelp32, ShellApi,
 Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Menus, System.Win.Registry;
type
 TMainMenu = class(TForm)
 constructor TMainMenu; overload;
 procedure RunOnWinStart(RunOnce: Boolean);
 private
   { Private declarations }
 public
   { Public declarations }
 end;

var
 MainMenu: TMainMenu;
 lclCurrProc: TProcessEntry32;
 lclPrntProc: TProcessEntry32;
 lclSnapHndl: THandle;
 lclEXEName: string;
 lclPrntName: string;
 myFileName: string;
 myFilePath: string;
 FullPath: string;
 Reg: TRegistry;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ }
/// <summary>
/// RunOnWinStart
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="RunOnce"></param>
/// <returns>None</returns>
procedure TMainMenu.RunOnWinStart(RunOnce: Boolean);
var
 TheKey: string;
begin
 myFileName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
 myFilePath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
 try
   Reg := TRegistry.Create;
   Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   TheKey := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run';
   if RunOnce then
     TheKey := TheKey + 'Once';
   Reg.OpenKey(TheKey, True);
   Reg.WriteString(myFileName, FullPath);
 finally
   Reg.CloseKey;
   Reg.Free;
 end;
end;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
/// <summary>
/// TMainMenu
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>None</returns>
constructor TMainMenu.TMainMenu;
begin
 TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
 Application.ShowMainForm := False;
 RunOnWinStart(False);
end;
```

Comment: There are countless SO questions about writing to HKLM - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594940/delphi-writing-to-hkey-local-machine.

Comment: In addition, `TRegistry` uses `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` by default. Change the `Access` property to `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead. And don't ignore the return value of `OpenKey()`, and check the `LastError/Msg` properties when something fails.

Comment: Off topic, but I immediately see a major bug in your code. You do `try Reg := TRegistry.Create; {...} finally Reg.CloseKey; Reg.Free`. This means that, if the `TRegistry` constructor fails (raises an exception, which is perfectly allowed), you will do `Reg.CloseKey` and `Reg.Free` on a random pointer (since local variables of non-managed types are not initialized). You **must** put `Reg := TRegistry.Create;` **before** the `try`. *Update:* OK, I see that `Reg` isn't a local variable, but a global (which is a problem in itself). Still, then you do `Reg.CloseKey` on a `nil` pointer which is also

Comment: bad. **Always** put the `X := TMyThing.Create` **before** the `try`: `X := TMyThing.Create; try {do things with X} finally X.Free; end;`

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have some things to research now. Also @RemyLebeau are you saying I should add an IF statement using the return value of `OpenKey()`?

Comment: Also, naming the constructor `TMainMenu.TMainMenu` will make almost every Delphi developer *highly* confused! In Delphi, the name of a constructor is *not* the name of the class, but typically `Create`. In fact, I have been developing in Delphi for more than 20 years, and I have never seen such a constructor name before! So please name it `TMainMenu.Create`! (Also, `TMainMenu` is the name of a common VCL class, namely, the one used to create menu bars. So you have an identifier conflict there. Maybe you could name your form class `TMainForm` instead? Then the ctor will be `TMainForm.Create`).

Comment: @Gean yes, that is what I am saying, eg: `if Reg.OpenKey(TheKey, True) then begin Reg.WriteString(myFileName, FullPath); end else begin {error handling...} end;`

Comment: You are aware that you would need to run with elevated privileges 'even if you are administrator) to write to that regkey? In XP this would have worked but since W7 we have something called "[UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/developing-applications-that-require-administrator-privilege)"

Comment: All of these are great lessons. I am sure it is evident that I still have a lot to learn. Thank you all for the input. I will make edits and repost.

Comment: @whosrdaddy so after some research on UAC "Thank you for that btw." I see that managing UAC at runtime is difficult if not impossible.(This may sound stupid but) Would it be possible/easier to make a work around by creating a shortcut to the start folder instead of writing to registry?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access all parts of the registry, be sure to open your project with Run as administrator.

Otherwise you can only access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and have read access only.

Here's the code I'm using(for read key, for write need open project by Run as administrator):

```
 function  Getreg:string;
 var
    Reg: TRegistry;
 begin 
   try
   reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
   with  reg do
   begin
     try
       RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ;
       if OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',false) then
       begin
         result:=readString('Once');
       end;
     finally
       CloseKey;
       free;
     end;
   end;
   finally

   end;
 end
```

Comment: The only way to write is to get your project with Run as admin.